# How to make converted classes from an XSD file reside in their own class files?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, xsd, xsd.exe

I using the XSD.exe provided in Visual Studio Tools to generate classes from an XSD file.  Currently all of the classes are generated in 1 CS file.  Is it possible to have each class generated into separate CS files?

Comment: Not as-is.  You'd have to use some other tool to separate the classes.  One drawback to doing that is it's easier to get the classes out-of-sync with the schema.

Comment: @DStanley Stanley"Good point.  I hadn't thought about that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[ReSharper](http://www.jetbrains.com/resharper/) can do this. Right-click on the generated cs file -> Refactor -> Move types into matching files. But i would recommend to keep it in one file, cause of the reason D Stanley mentioned.